# Snowflake schema training question Badge 1: Data Warehousing Workshop Lesson 3 Challenging Lab

Tags: snowflake-schema

I'd like to get answer to this question on snowflake training "You created the schema called VEGGIES but when you run the SHOW SCHEMAS command (see above) it does not appear. Assuming your current worksheet role has access to the schema, what options below would make the schema appear in the results?" Selections are below, and select all that apply.
Change your default role to SYSADMIN (and run again).
Set the worksheet database drop menu to GARDEN_PLANTS (and run again).
Set the worksheet warehouse drop menu to VEGGIES_WH (and run again).
Add "all" to the show schemas command (and run again).
Add "in account" to the show schemas command (and run again).
Add "where schema = 'VEGGIES' " to the show schemas command (and run again).

Thanks!

Comment: Hi - you’d probably get a better response if you updated your question to show which answer(s) you thought were correct and why - rather than asking someone to just give you the answer to your  coursework

Answer (score 0):

Hint is to reference to the photo above the question.  Remember that you are currently in SYSADMIN role and notice the selected database applied.

Apply what has been selected to your own worksheet.  Test the answer choices one by one and you'll notice some answer choices aren't real steps to take.  The question wasn't necessarily hard, but I also spend some time on this b/c I didn't digest the question/answer choices slowly and carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Check the 2nd and 5th checkboxes:

[image]